# Removing lock from file after import it as a python module (not unloading!)

Tags: python

After importing a Python shared library module, I have it in cache. The module is contained in two files `src.mymodule.pyi` and `src.mymodule.so`. Now I want to delete the .so-file.  However it seems that Windows has the file locked and I cannot delete it. In contrast to other discussions I do **not** want to unload it. Instead I just want to delete the module - either by force or by removing the lock of Windows and then deleting it. Is this possible and if so, how?

The weird thing is that this is no issue in Linux, simly by using `os.remove('src.mymodule.so')`. There I was able to import the module and then delete the file. How come there is such a discrepency compared to Windows?

Comment: `The weird thing is that this is no issue in Linux` it's nothing weird here. Linux handles that operation differently and lock is not stopping anything from deleting opened files as the way its done do not affect process holding the lock

Comment: Is this feature really all that important to your application?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: With "weird" I meant, "I don't know how this works", not "this must literally be black magic" :-).

Comment: @Todd: Yes, it is crucial.